# How can i center my login form both vertically and horizontally with a nav bar

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. I've been using this template from bootstrap:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sign-in/

But im trying to add a navbar on top of it. The styling in the framework is added onto the body to make it center. The problem i am having right now is that if i add a navbar get's centered aswell since its also in the body I've tried to add custom classes but that won't help me so far. this is what i have so far for it.

Form:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Vul hier je login 
gegevens</h1>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" 
type="submit">Inloggen</button>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2018</p>
        </form>
```

Nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background-color:#fe5f55;">
<div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Container</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample07" aria-controls="navbarsExample07" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample07">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Css:

```
* {

}
html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

body{
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
text-align:center;
}

.form-signin {
width: 100%;
max-width: 330px;
padding: 15px;
margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
margin-bottom: -1px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

button.btn-block {
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#fe5f55;
}
```

If anyone can help me out here with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try removing display flex from the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add css styling to your navbar, the following should help:

```
 .navbar { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this will keep the navbar fixed to the top of the browser window - the width is up to you but i often find navigation bars to be full width. hope this helps. If not please provide a JSFiddle example and i will look at it there.

Comment: Hello Harrison,

This worked for me the only question that i have now is that what will happen if i make a new page? The body styling remains the same. So on a new page the content will also be styled to the center. I only want my login page to be like that which classes do i need to add in order to prevent that from happening?


Greetings,

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a seperate css file only for your login page and another one for your main templates of pages. Currently we use angular where i work and while we have a common/main css file for the solution, we also have individual css files for each page (component) too. An alternative could be to look at using sections to also direct your css more specifically to target just the login page. In my opinion this is more of a workaround than using different css files for different pages, but thats your decision:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: stretch;` to your flex-container, which is `body` in your case:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background-color:#fe5f55;">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Container</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample07" aria-controls="navbarsExample07" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample07">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Vul hier je login gegevens
  </h1>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Inloggen</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2018</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the working example of it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .center{
      width: 500px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .height{
      height:100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Page 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="height">

  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Vul hier je login gegevens
      </h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Inloggen</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2018</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

check the fiddle out resize the screen to see navbar and form effect:https://jsfiddle.net/0vu83eru/7/